# Android - How to perform an HTTP GET request?

Tags: android, http, connection, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to perform an HTTP get request, to download something from a web page (text or image).

What I need is to build a class that allows me to do that and use it in my app when i need it.

The idea is to have two methods:

1. to download text from a url (return me a String)
2. to download image (return me a Bitmap)

**Example**: I have a URL where there is an image, I use my method `downloadBitmap()` to get it and then i can do what I want. Like put it into an `ImageView` for display.

Sample code is appreciated.

Comment: Try...
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11411209/bitmapfactory-decodestream-cannot-decode-png-type-from-ftp

May be enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Apache HTTP Client library. It is included in the Android platform.

The answers to the questions below should cover what you need to know.

- [Reading Text File From Server on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922210/reading-text-file-from-server-on-android)
- [Load image from url in Android, only if small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328898/load-image-from-url-in-android-only-if-small)

Comment: It's also good idea to put it in [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), so app won't freeze while downloading

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, but i think that i will use this:
http://code.google.com/p/android-query/